# How to create RHEL 8 to use on Windows System for Linux?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Problem**

I do not see RHEL 8 in the Windows 10 Pro store, as a WSL option to buy or use. I see Kali Linux, Ubuntu, Alpine Linux, SUSE 12 Enterprise, Debian, and every other Linux distribution, except for RHEL 8, what may be the most widely used distro in the enterprise, certainly in the top three.

It is an option from a pull down in every cloud provider when creating a VM, but not in the Windows store.

**How do I install/run RHEL 8 under WSL (by any means, if it's not in the store, and may not be ever)?**

If anyone has had any luck with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Provide background including what you've already tried.**

I have tried installing RHEL 8 under Virtual Box, it fails, crashes, jittery, no screen, significant mouse problems.  I get VirtualBox warnings from the RHEL install that this will not work in the first place as it's not tested.

RHEL does not put any time, energy or effort into validating that it will run under Oracle VirtualBox.

**Describe expected and actual results including any error messages.**

I want to be able to goto the Windows store, download in a click, install RHEL 8, then when running, enter my developer license key, run **#yum update -y**, get going.

I can do this, exactly as described with SUSE 12 Enterprise and every other linux distro out there.

---

If instructions are provided, how would I roll my own RHEL 8 artifacts for use in WSL ( have it installed on a NUC that I could do something with there ).

Comment: The [Pengwin-Enterprise](https://github.com/WhitewaterFoundry/Pengwin-Enterprise) provides some enterprise things. You can contact them. But if there is any tarball of rootfs of RHEL then anyone can install it.

Answer (score 0):

***You will have to create this distro yourself*** and I am not so sure how RHEL's licensing junk will play.  I am *mostly* sure RedHat's lawyers won't like it.

You will probably have a lot more luck targeting CENTOS or Fedora.

[This is a generic project from MS](https://github.com/Microsoft/wsl-distrolauncher)   to make your own distro for WSL..

[This is a General purpose WSL installer](https://github.com/yuk7/wsldl)  and does not appear to be from MS.  It looks like it is for anything.

[This is a modified version of the above project](https://github.com/yuk7/CentWSL)  That claims to be specific to CENTOS.

Good luck

Comment: You can also install fedora from rootfs.